# Problems sampling D3D11 depth buffer

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, hlsl, depth-buffer

I'm getting everything ready in a little DirectX 11.0 project of mine for a deferred rendering pipeline. However, I've been having quite a lot of trouble with sampling the depth buffer from within a pixel shader.

First I define the depth texture and its shader resource view:

```
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC depthTexDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&depthTexDesc, sizeof(depthTexDesc));
    depthTexDesc.Width = nWidth;
    depthTexDesc.Height = nHeight;
    depthTexDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32_TYPELESS;
    depthTexDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    depthTexDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    depthTexDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    depthTexDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    depthTexDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    depthTexDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    depthTexDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    depthTexDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

    hresult = d3dDevice_->CreateTexture2D(&depthTexDesc, nullptr, &depthTexture_);

    D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC DSVDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&DSVDesc, sizeof(DSVDesc));
    DSVDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT;
    DSVDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    DSVDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;

    hresult = d3dDevice_->CreateDepthStencilView(depthTexture_, &DSVDesc, &depthView_);

    D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC gbDepthTexDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&gbDepthTexDesc, sizeof(gbDepthTexDesc));
    gbDepthTexDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT;
    gbDepthTexDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    gbDepthTexDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;
    gbDepthTexDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = -1;

    d3dDevice_->CreateShaderResourceView(depthTexture_, &gbDepthTexDesc, &gbDepthView_);
```

Here's the relevant part of my rendering function:

```
    float clearColor[4] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    d3dContext_->ClearRenderTargetView(backBufferTarget_, clearColor);
    d3dContext_->ClearDepthStencilView(depthView_, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH, 1.0f, 0);

    // GBuffer packing pass (in the future): /////////////////////////////////////////

    d3dContext_->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &backBufferTarget_, depthView_);

    unsigned int nStride = sizeof(Vertex);
    unsigned int nOffset = 0;

    d3dContext_->IASetInputLayout(inputLayout_);
    d3dContext_->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &vertexBuffer_, &nStride, &nOffset);
    d3dContext_->IASetIndexBuffer(indexBuffer_, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);
    d3dContext_->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

    d3dContext_->VSSetShader(firstVS_, 0, 0);
    d3dContext_->PSSetShader(firstPS_, 0, 0);

    d3dContext_->DrawIndexed(nIndexCount_, 0, 0);

    d3dContext_->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &backBufferTarget_, nullptr);

    d3dContext_->VSSetShader(secondVS_, 0, 0);
    d3dContext_->PSSetShader(secondPS_, 0, 0);
    d3dContext_->PSGetShaderResources(0, 1, &gbDepthView_);
    d3dContext_->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &colorMapSampler_);

    d3dContext_->DrawIndexed(nIndexCount_, 0, 0);

    swapChain_->Present(0, 0);
```

In this temporary implementation, firstVS_ and secondVS_ are identical, and their only function is to do all the transforms and pass on the data to the PSs.

And finally, here are firstPS_ and secondPS_:

```
// firstPS_
float4 main(PS_Input frag) : SV_TARGET
{
    return float4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
}

// secondPS_
Texture2D<float> depthMap_ : register(t0);
SamplerState colorSampler_ : register(s0);

float4 main(PS_Input frag) : SV_TARGET
{
    float4 psOut;
    psOut.xyz = depthMap_.Sample(colorSampler_, frag.tex0).xxx;
    psOut.w = 1.0f;
    return psOut;
}
```

**So, my actual questions:**

1) All this code compiles without any issues, but when I sample the depth buffer, it just turns out black. I read this could be caused by having your depth & stencil view bound by `D3D11DeviceContext::OMSetRenderTargets()` at the time you want to sample the depth buffer. I fixed that, but the buffer is still black. I checked the graphics debugger, with no success. So, is my depth buffer not getting written correctly, or am I sampling the wrong way? firstPS_ works fine.

2) Speaking of sampling, the book I'm using just says "we'll be using a point sampler," but I have no idea what is exactly meant. Now I'm just using a standard texture map sampler, but is there something else I should sample with?

3) Also, the book uses the `SamplerState.Gather()` function in secondPS_, but when I tried that it complained that "the expression could not be mapped to pixel shader instruction set." Is `Gather()` an error in the book, or is it my GPU (D3D feature level 11.0) who doesn't understand what that is? Is `Sample()` good enough for what I want to do? The original use of `Gather()` was in the context of creating a silhouette around objects in the depth buffer.

4) I tried to get secondVS_ to draw nothing but a full-screen quad, but FXC complained about my use of `SV_VertexID` as "invalid," saying that my type should be integral, even though it already was. I read somewhere that `SV_VertexID` can only be used by the first VS in a pipeline. Is that the problem here? How do I solve this in this particular case? In my current inefficient solution, is the problem being caused by the UVs?

Comment: Did you enabled the debug layer? Such errors like setting a resource as input as well as output are very easy to detect with the debug messages. Always my first step, if something returns unexpected black.

Comment: The debug layer is on for sure, and all state creation warnings are #0. I still have no idea what's going wrong.

Comment: Why is MostDetailedMip set to -1 in the SRV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You've called PSGetShaderResources instead of PSSetShaderResources. Also, MostDetailedMip should be 0 not -1.

2) A "point sampler" is just a texture sampler with the FILTER field set to something like D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_POINT.

3) Gather is a function on the Texture2D not the SamplerState as you stated.

4) You get this error if you compile using vs_4_0, try vs_5_0.

Comment: Thank you for all your anwers, they all helped, though when I reviewed my code I found MostDetailedMip to be already set to 0. And I can't believe I missed that typo. While everything is registering correctly, my depth buffer seems to be filled with 1.0f values only. I'll mark your answer once that's fixed.